# Flutter Column with multiple Expandeds returns Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter

My code:

```
Column(
  children: const [
    Expanded(child: AssetsMap()),
    Expanded(child: AssetList()),
  ],
)
```

Returns:

> The following assertion was thrown while looking for parent data.:
> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
>
> The following ParentDataWidgets are providing parent data to the same
> RenderObject:
>
> - Expanded(flex: 1) (typically placed directly inside a Flex widget)
> - Expanded(flex: 1) (typically placed directly inside a Flex widget) However, a RenderObject can only receive parent data from at most one
>   ParentDataWidget.

What is the problem?

Comment: It is unclear because of `AssetsMap` and `AssetList` are unknown.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I mentioned in my answer that the problem was that I had an unnecessary `Expanded` in my `AssetList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue solved.

Checkout the flutter [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/common-errors#incorrect-use-of-parentdata-widget) about this issue.

In my case, There was another inner `Expanded` widget in `AssetList`. All I had to do is to remove it.